# Is a small size block cipher usable?

Tags: block-cipher, blocksize

Consider a block cipher with a key of size 128 bits but a small block size, say 32 bits.  Is this kind of block cipher secure?

I would like to know to what extent I can use a small block cipher, like a 32 bit block cipher. What are the constraints so that the use is acceptable in a real life application.

For instance, if we use a one-time key, that is, to encrypt only one message. Besides, the message could be small.

Suppose that when we want so send one file, we perform a key agreement so that we use the key for one message. This scenario is not efficient, but the CPA find-then-guess game is not adequate in this case.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "secure".  It might be a secure pseudorandom permutation, even though it's not very useful in practice (e.g., not very useful in any standard mode of operation).  Which are you asking about?  I suggest you edit the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 13):

Such a block cipher would be completely unusable in any of the standard modes of operation, presuming you want at least IND-CPA security. Say, for instance, that you are using it in CTR mode. A chosen plain text adversary looking at a cipher text consisting of only two blocks (i.e. 2 times 32 bits), would have a non-negligible probability (higher than $2^{-32}$) of guessing if the cipher text is produced by your block cipher in CTR mode, or a random function.

This matters in so far that a block cipher in CTR mode is only secure up to the bound where the block cipher might still be modeled as a PRF, as defined in the [security proof](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=a%20concrete%20security%20treatment%20of%20symmetric%20encryption%20pdf&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/sym-enc.pdf&ei=zf3DUYbyEcaw4QSd-ID4Bg&usg=AFQjCNGuGU6TtmpXoeU7wcNQuCjx1c1zqQ&bvm=bv.48293060,d.bGE). If you are able to distinguish the block cipher from a PRF, CTR mode is no longer IND-CPA secure. This applies to all other standard modes as well.

If one of the CTR mode cipher texts is 16 GB, you will have revealed the entire code book, and the adversary will not need the key.

If you have a hard time seeing this, consider a 2-bit block cipher in CTR mode that has produced the ciphertext stream 3-1-0. If Eve has tricked us into encrypting 0 three times, then the next CTR value must be 2 with probability 100%. Real plaintexts are nearly that predictable, so exhaustion of the ciphertext space is a practical limit. 32 bits is just too tight.

**Edit:**
Please also note that it would be a mistake to assume that failure to meet IND-CPA security, would only be relevant in scenarios where the exact CPA game can be played out. Suppose, for instance, that you encrypt only a single message (in CTR mode) with each key, and that this message is $l$ bits long. If $l \le 32$ you are safe, but if it is longer, you are not. Suppose $l=64$. In such case the plain text $m$ might be divided into two blocks $m=m_0|m_1$ and the cipher text $c$ into two blocks $c=c_0|c_1$. Now, the attacker might immediately deduce that $m_1\ne m_0\oplus c_0 \oplus c_1$ (because $m_i \oplus c_i = E_k(i)$ and $E_k(0) \ne E_k(1)$) and has learned $32/{2^{32}}=2^{-27}$ bits of information about $m$. The more that is known of patterns in $m$ and the greater the length $l$, the more information about $m$ might be deduced even in a cipher text only attack.

Comment: For 32-bit block sizes I think a few hundred megabytes of output should be sufficient to distinguish between a CTR keystream and a random function, actually, assuming the plaintext has sufficient structure.

Comment: @Thomas: That, of course, depends on the confidence coefficient, as well as what is known of the plain text. As I wrote in my answer, you really only need two known plain text blocks to be more likely right than wrong if you guess it is CTR cipher text if there is no repetition.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I don't understand how an adversary having only a ciphertext of two blocks (and the corresponding plaintext) can distinguish between the block cipher in CTR mode and a random function ? If we speak about the randomized CTR and that the adversary sees several pair (plaintext, ciphertext) I think that I can understand, but if the adversary has only one pair... ?

Comment: @user7060: If you got two CTR mode key stream blocks, you know that, since the counter never repeats, the second key stream block cannot be equal to the first. A random function might otoh repeat. The probability of such repetitions increase with the amount of known plain text you are analyzing, and it is non zero starting from the second block. Suppose the adversary submits a plain text to the challenger, which returns either random data or CTR mode cipher text. If there is a repetition, the adversary will know it is random data.

Comment: In a CPA game the adversary will first submit a bounded number of encryption requests to the oracle, which in the case of a block cipher with a 32 bit block size will rule out large portions of the code book. This means that the adversary might choose the two challenge plain texts $m_0,m_1$ such that, regardless of which of the yet unknown cipher text blocks will be used in the key stream, the odds will be low that the adversary will be able to tell which of the two plain texts the adversary encrypted.

Comment: Thank you Henrick Hellström, this CPA game is not the same that your previous message. If we can distinguish between a random function and the mode of encryption, is this encryption really not secure ? Besides, you speak about the deterministic CTR, and there exists the randomized version in which the IV is random, what about this case ?

Comment: @user7060: Presume the random oracle adversary is that it is always right when it outputs "random". Let $R_i$ be the set of cipher texts for which the adversary outputs "random" for plain text $m_i$. If the adversary is able to select $m_0,m_1$ and grow the sets $R_0$ and $R_1$ in such way that they still don't overlap, but there is a non-negligible probability the CPA challenger will return a cipher text in either set given $m_0,m_1$, you have a CPA distinguisher. For a 32 bit block cipher, this happens to be true for the standard modes.

Comment: @user7060: If the IV is random you can't neglect the possibility that you get state collisions, which makes things even easier for the CTR mode CPA adversary.

Comment: @Henrick Hellström, sometimes you write "adversary" instead of "challenger", this is somewhat confusing... Besides you speak about the set $(R_i)$ or $R_i$ is a set at its own ? In this latter case $(R_i)$ is a sequence of sets

Comment: @user7060: The adversary and the challenger are different entities. Suggested reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability

Comment: @henrick Hellström, thank you. When you say "for which the adversary outputs "random" for plain text $m_i$", you want to say that the adversary chooses $m_i$ at random, or you want to say that the challenger returns a random value for the queried $m_i$ ? thank you again.

Comment: The adversary submits $m_i$ to the challenger, gets $c$ in return and outputs "random" if it is able to tell $c$ can't be a cipher text produced by the block cipher under the assumed mode and key.

Comment: OK, In fact I think that I don't understand what means "random" in this case. You speak about the random guess, at the end of the game ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9309/discussion-between-user7060-and-henrick-hellstrom)

Answer (score 3):

As pointed in this [other answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/8772/555), a 32-bit block cipher with 128-bit key can be practically unsafe when used with the [standard operating modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). However, it is still fine in some other uses.

For example, we can derive a wide shared secret from the initial 128-bit $K$, say as the concatenation of $E_K(3\cdot i)\oplus E_K(3\cdot i+1)\oplus E_K(3\cdot i+2)$ for $i$ in range $[0\dots(2^{32}-4)/3]$, which <strike>is</strike> *may be* [update: I wildly conjecture, without proof or even strong argument, and thus imprudently; see hand-waving attempts of coming with justification in my comments] computationally indistinguishable from a random sequence of $(2^{37}-32)/3$ bits (I use three terms because with just one, all the blocks are different. And with two, the all-zero block can not occur). We can then use the above random sequence in a stream cipher.

Comment: http://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2000/1807/18070476-new.pdf

Comment: Intuitively, this makes sense, but do you know of a better security proof, than the one in the link in the comment above? How do you prove that the construct does better than preserve security of the underlying block encryptor?

Comment: @Henrick Hellström:  I have no proof of my assertion (any attack that I can think of is beyond unworkable, but that should not convince anyone, including me). The construct pass an entropic acid test: defining an arbitrary 32-bit permutation requires $\log_2(2^{32}!)$ bits, we disclose $(2^{37}-32)/3$ bits, about $2.86$ times less. I did not feel confident enough to propose $E_K(2⋅i)⊕\operatorname{RORL}(E_K(2⋅i+1),1)$ for $i$ in range $[0…2^{31}−2]$, although I have no working attack either. The reference that you quote XORs distinct random permutations, thus its proof does not apply to mine.

Comment: It might be a mere curiosity, but I did a full computation of all permutations with a 3 bit and 4 bit block size, and for such small block sizes the output sequence was far from uniformly distributed. Isn't it generally dangerous to just assume it would be indistinguishable from uniform for block sizes that are so small that the permutation is in principle searchable?

Comment: @Henrick Hellström: Starting with $8$ bits, the $2^{128}$ keyspace allows only for a tiny subsample of the possible output sequences (there are $2^{680}$ for 8 bits, $2^{45812984480}$ for 32 bits); therefore, any consideration on a **small** bias in the output sequences is moot (further, I expect that this bias you observed quickly evens out). What would matter very much would be that some of the output sequences can not be reached for any input permutation.