# Calculating DES key knowing message before and after encryption

Tags: des

I've 8 bytes before encryption (for example: `01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08`) and 8 bytes after DES encryption: `08 07 06 06 05 04 03 02 01`. Is it possible to calculate the key?

Comment: What you mean by DSA encryption?

Comment: DES key can be searched within [25 seconds](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62772/18298) with special hardware and  $2^{56}$ is it is quite achievable by [supercomputers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63537/18298)

Answer (score 1):

A single [p3.16xlarge](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/p3/) EC2 instance is [capable](https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-6972.html) of evaluating $369\times10^9 \approx 2^{38}$ DES calls per second using hashcat.

This puts the maximum time to recover a key at around $2^{56} / 369\times10^9 / 3600 \approx 54$ hours. This costs a little over $1300 at current [pricings](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/).